# Mapping arrays to strings efficiently in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json

I want to load data using AJAX without formatting it as JSON, so I encoded it myself.

The data is client records: the pound sign (`#`) separates client records, the pipe sign (`|`) separates the client data’s fields, and the carat sign (`^`) separates the field name from that field’s value.

So, I have something like this (Simplified):

```
name^James|email^somemail@gmail.com#name^Bary|email^bary@bary.com#...
```

When loading this data into Javascript, I want to make it into a 2-dimensional array, like this:

```
clients = [
['name'=>'James','email'=>'somemail@gmail.com'],
['name'=>'Bary','email'=>bary@bary.com]
]
```

... Or alternatively something in object format. How best to do this?

Comment: Why can't you use JSON?

Comment: because It's not working well with my language

Comment: Wich language are you using?

Comment: There should be no problem using JSON.

Comment: Hebrew and I get utf8 signs

Comment: @Yaakov What is the problem? Set the document's encoding to UTF-8 and you should be able to display them just fine.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: @JoeFrambach, that link is awesome.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason whatsoever why any sane programming platform you choose on either end wouldn't be able to be set up to handle Hebrew characters encoded in UTF-8, and correctly round-trip them through JSON. Fix your JSON de-serialisation.

Comment: PHP earlier than 5.4 can only kinda-sorta do it. PHP prior to 5.4 really really sucks at encoding things.

Comment: Lol at the link. but This X-Problem is a true problem because I've tried everything in order to fix this encoding problem, including like suggested to encode the file itself to Utf8, and also to encode the string to Utf8 with php-native utf8_encode(). So if you really think my X-Problem is solvable, then please let me know. Thank You.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Hence: "sane".

Comment: @Yaakov I really think your "X Problem" is solvable because I ferry non-ASCII data over JSON in UTF-8 *all* the time, as do many, many, many websites, some of them very likely written in PHP. You're welcome. (Now if you need help actually solving it, you'll have to make a proper question about it, one that involves pinpointing **exactly** where the data gets corrupted. I.e. at what string->bytes encoding/output step does the resulting byte array for a known test string not match what's expected.)

Comment: That said, if you're using PHP for a Hebrew site, that's the problem I'd fix. Especially in a web programming language having strings be just byte arrays by default is staggeringly dumb. (Seeing as HTTP already has mechanisms that indicate the charset of a request or response.)

Comment: Maybe you can base64-encode it

Comment: If you are unwilling to wrap your head around the real issue (which is _NOT_ the JSON, rather your inability to properly handle text encoding) and you INSIST on using some format other than JSON, then use XML. Magic strings are very bad and unmaintainable. You need a portable serialization scheme (XML or JSON). In the end, I don't see you solving the real issue no matter what transport format you come up with. The issue is not in the transport.

Answer (score 0):

Beware, you can't use the special characters (|,^,#) in either key or value. If you decide to encode them, then you likely can use JSON. SO I really recommend JSON so you don't have to do anything yourself.

If you decide to not support keys and values containing (|,^,#) then you can use the javascript split function. Something like this (I haven't run it):

```
var output=[];
var clients = input.split("#");

for (var client in clients)
{
  var outputClient={}
  var clientProps = client.split('|');
  for (var propPair in clientProps)
  {
     var propPairVal = propPair.split('^');
     outputClient[propPairVal[0]] = propPairVal[1];  
  }
  output.push(outputClient);
}
```

However, I really recommnend JSON. It will be much more flexible and less bug prone.

Comment: Thanks. I CAN'T use Json unfortunately. What other signs can I use?

Comment: @Yaakov: So instead of figuring out how to use JSON properly, you back yourself into a corner by writing your own format?